# an unknown js file on my Web server

Tags: javascript, virus, trojan

I'm new in managing Web server, I maintain the server and make sure the server works for other web programmer, I found a js file that maybe malicious, I check the web server log, the JS file is included by a site I didn't know, the portion of web log :

```
[23/Dec/2012:04:03:59 +0800] "GET /l/zj.js HTTP/1.0" 200 52591 "http://www.observechina.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; KB974488)"

[23/Dec/2012:04:10:37 +0800] "GET /l/zj.js HTTP/1.0" 304 - "http://www.observechina.net/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"

[23/Dec/2012:04:10:39 +0800] "GET /l/zj.js HTTP/1.0" 304 - "http://www.observechina.net/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"

[23/Dec/2012:04:12:03 +0800] "GET /l/zj.js HTTP/1.1" 200 52591 "http://www.observechina.net/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; @h%Ag|1%|x/O{ZqBsQ_R{=q?TnQk+&rpJrB-+_; msn OptimizedIE8;ZHCN; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: zqbah3)"
```

The JS file is :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IGLK5OlrgsSregEo8AahlyhcjgUJgftQ6Imm8NIZjWM/edit

Is the JS file really malicious?? Do I delete it??

Comment: Having us take a look at a potentially malicious script? Who would even dare?

Comment: "Do you delete it?" Did you upload it? No? Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a file from openjfx.
Someone would have put it there for some reason.

Comment: OK~thank you, it's not a malicious file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know where it originated, plus the file came from "observechina.net"? hmm...

Malicious or not, it does not originate from you. I would suggest just delete it.

If that file is really important, someone would have a backup somewhere.

Comment: +1 for the nice Assumption :-D "If that file is really important, someone would have a backup somewhere." Gotta print that out and hang it on my office wall.